# How to delete chat rooms when we're done chatting?

Tags: support, chat

Chat rooms always show up even there is no user activity at a present time. Chat rooms stay even after days. How to delete them? And can we delete them?

No one is going to learn things from a chat anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any chat which contains [more than 15 messages by at least two users](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention) is considered a public artifact; it will automatically be frozen (which prevents further activity and removes it from the default room list display) if it remains inactive for two weeks.

If a room does not reach this threshold, it will delete itself after a week.